# Code Igniter file upload saying path is invalid

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am creating some file upload functionality utilizing the upload library within the Code Igniter framework and I am having an issue where I keep on getting an error back stating that my file upload path is incorrect. I have checked many times and there is no issue with the file structure and the files definitely exist.

Here is my model upload code (I am dieing to check where I am within the process):

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model {

    var $gallery_path;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images/profileImages');
        //$this->gallery_path = realpath($this->config->base_url() . 'images/profileImages');

    }

    public function doUpload() {
        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
            'upload_path'   => $this->gallery_path
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            die(print_R($data));
        } else {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            die(print_R($error));
        }
    }

}
```

My images folder is outside of the application and is called 'images', which contains a folder called 'profileImage' where I want this files to save. I get the following error:

'The upload path does not appear to be valid.'

I can't for the life of me figure out why this path is not working when it definitely exists. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Upload only ever worked for me if I closed the path with slash, in your case `$this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . 'images/profileImages/');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter will only return that error message if `$config['upload_path']` is blank or the php command `is_dir($config['upload_path'])` returns false.  Check to make sure the 'uploads' folder is in the same directory as main index.php file and that the directory name is the same case

Answer (score 1):

Is your images folder in the web root?  If is this should work

```
$this->gallery_path = './images/profileImages/';
```